# Problems with Logger in JUnit test case (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'd like to ask for some help with an error in Eclipse that I've researched but haven't found much about. I'm a Java beginner and I've been following [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-introtojava1/) tutorial from IBM DeveloperWorks.

Things were fine until I wrote up the "Figure 9 See Person Run" JUnit Test code, under "Your first Java class":

```
package com.makotojava.intro;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class PersonTest1 {

    @Test
    public void testPerson() {
        Person p = new Person("Joe Q Author", 42, 173, 82, "Brown", "MALE");
        Logger l = Logger.getLogger(Person.class.getName());
        l.info("Name: " + p.getName());
        l.info("Age:" + p.getAge());
        l.info("Height (cm):" + p.getHeight());
        l.info("Weight (kg):" + p.getWeight());
        l.info("Eye Color:" + p.getEyeColor());
        l.info("Gender:" + p.getGender());
        assertEquals("Joe Q Author", p.getName());  
        assertEquals(42, p.getAge());
        assertEquals(173,p.getHeight());
        assertEquals(82, p.getWeight());
        assertEquals("Brown", p.getEyeColor());
        assertEquals("MALE", p.getGender());
    }

}
```

For Line 13, beginning with "Logger l" the error is: "Multiple markers at this line
    - Line breakpoint:PersonTest1 [line: 13] - testPerson()
    - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
    - Logger cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete"

For Lines 14-19 (the l.info lines) the error is: "Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
     Assignment
    - The method info(String) is undefined for the type PersonTest1
-The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

If it's relevant, I troubleshooted a bit previously by deleting and re-adding JUnit3, JUnit4, and JRE System Library in Build Path.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions as to how I might resolve these errors... Thank you very much and my apologies if this question is silly!

Comment: Please post the code you have (including import statements).

Comment: Probably it is about parenthesis () matching... Check line 11 and 12... Also you should post code, instead of links. that makes it easy for quick lookup and reference.

Comment: You may not use `1` as a variable name. Use, I don't know, `logger` for example.

Comment: Oh wow, of course! Thank you. I've done that and now the error that shows up for Line 13 is: "- Line breakpoint:PersonTest1 [line: 13] - testPerson()
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
 - Logger cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete"

Comment: For line 14-19 the error is: "- Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
 - The method info(String) is undefined for the type PersonTest1
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable" (so same errors??)

Comment: Edit your question, post the new code, post the exact error message, and tell us which line it refers to.

Comment: Update: I opened up the file again after editing and there are no error messages. Thanks so much! :)